# Unable to install nss-pam-ldapd on CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Tags: centos, yum

When I try to yum install nss-pam-ldapd on CentOS 6.8 I get the following:

```
$ sudo yum install nss-pam-ldapd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
No package nss-pam-ldapd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What to do?

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repolist: 0
```

Comment: Is it already installed?  `rpm -q nss-pam-ldapd`

Comment: nope. package nss-pam-ldapd is not installed

Comment: Please update the question with the output of `yum repolist` so we can be sure you're configured to talk to a repo properly.

Comment: You don't have any repo's enabled, which either means they've all been disabled in `/etc/yum.repos.d` or not defined.  You should have a file similar to `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` that lists the base repo's.  In it should be an entry for `[base]`.  If that has `enabled=0` in it then delete the `enabled` line.  Similarly  for `[updates]` section.